# Converting geodata frame to networkx in python

Tags: python, networkx, geopandas, dijkstra

How to convert geodataframe to networkx? And how to insert shape file data to dijestras shortest path algorithm.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What type of geometries do you have in the dataframe points, or polygons?